# issue with viewing pdf file using vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, dompdf

I generate pdf files using the laravel dompdf wrapper. but I want to render that generated pdf files with my client-side vuejs app. I wrote a response code to view that pdf file and it's downloaded. but my requirement is to open that pdf in another tab.

```
 const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response]));
 const link = document.createElement('a');
 link.href = url;
 link.setAttribute('download', 'test.pdf');
 document.body.appendChild(link);
 link.click();
```

can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

i found a way to open using new window. i think this will help someone who when generate PDFs with dompdf wrapper.

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res]));
const link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = url;
link.setAttribute('href', 'invoice.pdf');
link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```